# AxWindowsMediaPlayer - how to set video border color programmatically

Tags: c#, .net, axwindowsmediaplayer

if you play video using Windows Media Player, there is an option "Video border color" in "Options"\"Performance". Default color is black.

How can I set color to white programmatically, when using AxWindowsMediaPlayer component in WinForms?

Prereq: .NET 4.0, WMP 12 for Windows 7

Thanks a lot